is not defined error - but whats missing?
Error:

$ is not defined - when i use F12 to look at the debugger its coming up with $ is not defined

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#form").validationEngine({
    ajaxSubmit: true,
    ajaxSubmitFile: "ajaxSubmit.php",
    ajaxSubmitMessage: "Thank you, your post has been sent!",
    success: false,
    ajaxSubmitMessage: "Failed to send",
    failure: function () {},
  });
});


Javascript being used has syntax errors. Check the browser developer console and note the error you are getting

its saying $ is not defined ...

How could it say success if $ isn't even defined ... oh wait, you've changed the question completely

Well did you load the jQuery library that the code is apparently using?

Check in your html page if you have defined the jquery library. You can find a guide at w3schools linked here
Essentially you will have to link the library like this:
<head>
<!--This part is required to run jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 

